# Progress 4GL how to see th Before image file size in progress DB server

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, progress-db

> How to see the before image file size in progress DB server?

Answer (score 1):

ls -l

Or, if you're running Windows:

DIR

Or you can get some info from VSTs (Virtual System Tables) like _Logging._Logging-BiLogSize.

Answer (score 0):

The Virtual System Tables are your best bet when checking from within a Progress program.

If you're checking the BI size from the command prompt:

- fire up ProMon on the database
- Choose the option R&D
- Choose option 1, Status displays
- Choose option 9, BI Log

This will show you the size of all the bi logs for this database.